# Responsive design with jQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, responsive-design

I have a website in which I animate elements through jQuery. My question is if there is some way that if you are being visited an iPad, you can make a call to a specific function file for a given resolution. In my head I've tried but changes the functionality of the entire page regardless of the size of the monitor.

General function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/funcionesSobre.js"></script>
```

Specific function.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iPadPortrait.css" media="only screen and (max-width : 768px) and (orientation : portrait)" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/funcionesPortrait.js" media="only screen and (max-width : 768px) and (orientation : portrait)"></script>
```

Can you adapt the design through jQuery or it can only be made with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Response JS may be suitable for your needs.

http://responsejs.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot. First of all I´ll try with $window.width(). Perhaps it´s better than responsejs.

Answer (score 0):

There is `matchMedia` and the `MediaQueryList` interface :

```
var mql = window.matchMedia('(min-width:769px)');
// window.matchMedia returns a MediaQueryList object

mql.matches // returns true if the document currently matches the mediaQuery

if(mql.matches) {
    // viewport is at least 769px
}
else {
    // viewport is 768px max
}
```

Or you can add listeners to MediaQueryList objects :

```
var media = window.matchMedia('(max-width:400px)');
media.addListener(handleMediaChange);

function handleMediaChange(mql) {
    if(mql.matches) {
        // viewport is 400px max
    }
    else {
        // viewport is 401px or more
    }
}
```

### Compatibility

- Chrome 9+
- Firefox 6+
- Safari 5.1+
- Opera 12.1+
- Internet Explorer 10+
- Safari Mobile 5+
- Android 3+

### Doc

- See [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.matchMedia) and [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) for MDN documentation
- See [github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js) for a polyfill
- See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/matchmedia) for compatibility table